# How can i add a folder to PATH for an ASP.NET exe?

Tags: asp.net

i use several exes for my asp.net prj. they include ffmpeg and imagemagik. I know i can easily put this in my path but i may want to switch between different version in different builds. How do i add the path based on my exe? doing it in code is ok. I'm thinking about using a prefix path as a workaround and just set the prefix path to the version i want.

note: i do not want to do this via IIS since i may use apache and i am debugging in VS.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to put an entry in your web.config file for each build.  in the AppSettings you can add a key/value for the path:  i.e. 
`<appSettings>
  <add key="Build1Folder" 
     value="c:\myBuild1\folder"/>
</appSettings>`

Comment: This would be using the prefix path right? prefix=Build1Folder; ... exename = prefix+binname; i'm using an ugly name. it would be called bindir or binfolder.

Comment: Actually you would use the ConfigurationManager to get the vaule for the key "Build1Folder". Then on subsequent builds...you would deploy with a new key/value pari in the web.config file. Like "Build2Folder" string myFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Build1Folder");

//the value of myFolder will be "C:\myBuild1\folder"